# AWS: Quickly get S3 bucket size using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I need a quick way to get an S3 bucket size using powershell.

Actually I used this command to calculate the actual size of an S3 bucket:

```
$size = (Get-S3Object -ProfileName $myacc -BucketName $myBucket |Measure-Object -Sum -Property Size).Sum
```

until I ran into a bucket with more than 50M of files. It took almost forever to calculate that.
Isn't there a way to quickly obtain the bucket size?
Well, I noticed in the Metrics section there is already the bucket size and the number of files.
I tried `Get-CWMetricsStatistic`, but no result. So I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: LIST requests are $0.005/1k and GET requests are $0.0004/1k ( https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ ) so could this have cost you $20 to sum the size of 50M objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get an S3 bucket size:

```
$MyProfile = "myprofile"
$EndDate = Get-Date
$StartDate = $EndDate.AddDays(-7)
$bucketName = "mybucket"
$dim = [Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension]::new()
$dim.Name = "BucketName"
$dim.Value = $bucketName
$dim2 = [Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension]::new()
$dim2.Name = "StorageType"
$dim2.Value = "StandardStorage"
$size = (Get-CWMetricStatistic -ProfileName  $MyProfile -Statistic Average -Period 86400 -Namespace AWS/S3 -UtcEndTime $EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -UtcStartTime $StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -MetricName BucketSizeBytes -Dimension $dim, $dim2 -Unit "Bytes" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Datapoints | select-object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$TotalSizeGB = 0

foreach ($item in (Get-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName | Select-Object Size)) { $TotalSizeGB += $item.Size/1GB }

$TotalSizeGB
```

Comment: This is the same technique used in the original question - querying every object in the bucket - and rejected for being too slow, but this code has the extra overhead that `Select-Object` will make a new PowerShell object for every item (tens of millions of them) which will only make it slower.